# Submitting ImageFields in Django Admin doesn't work

Tags: django, permissions, django-admin, wsgi

I have some models with ImageFields (that work fine on my home computer test environment). When I put the project on a server using Passenger WSGI, submitting a form in the admin containing an ImageField doesn't work.

If DEBUG is True, I get a 404 error page saying that it can't find 500.shtml (I didn't create a 500 error page). No error appears in the server console.

If DEBUG is False, I get an Apache message saying it can't find "admin/red_projects/project/add/" (the URL it was JUST at), and the server error log has a message saying that the folder admin doesn't exist in the filesystem (since it's not a directory, just a Django urlconf), or it just hangs and doesn't load the page.

I already recursively set the permissions on the media directory to 755, and that didn't do anything. Everything else works fine, including submitting admin forms without ImageFields.

Comment: When you say submitting the form doesn't work do you mean you get an error or do you mean the form submits but you can't see the image?

Answer (score 0):

Django dosn't serve media or static files when debug is False, you shoud have and alias in your configuration to serve them via the web server directly (Way faster than using django to serve them)

Read this, it will help you put it in production : [Deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/deployment/)

Edit: This is for static files, same things aply to media files